# Sorting results basing on a string variable content

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I would like to sort results by a specific order which I hold as a string

(the string is created programmatically).

Consider this table:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1       Jon     a
2       Joan    b
3       John    a
4       Jonnie  b
5       Jonny   a
```

I have an `nvarchar` variable declared as `@myOrderString`, which contains the order of rows I would like to select.

Let's say that `@myOrderString = '213'` (edited)

So, I would like to do something like that:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @mySortString) AS Row, 
    ( Col2 + '(' + Col1 + ')' ) AS Outcome
FROM 
    myTable 
WHERE 
    Col3 = 'a' 
ORDER BY 
    @mySortString
```

In order to get the outcome: (edited)

```
Row Outcome
1   John (3)
2   Jon (1)
3   Jonny (5)
```

How do I even start solving this?

P.S.

If the values in `@myOrderString` should be separated, I can make it `@myOrderString = '2,1,3'` (edited)

---

The reason for the editing the question:

1. There was an error in the string content. [marked as (edited)]
2. There was an error in the results. Thanks to Andriy M. [marked as (edited)]
3. I've added cosmetic changes and corrected some grammar and typos.

---

A clarification: (part of this clarification is based on the comment by Aaron Bertrand)

1. The number of values in the string is always matching the number of
   rows in the result.
2. The values in the string are always the numbers 1 to the row count.
3. The first result's row is marked as 1; the 2nd is marked as 2 and
   the third as 3. Now, the string is meant to reorder the result. when
   the string is `2,1,3` it means that the select result is reordered:
   the 2nd row will now result as the first, the first result will
   appear as second, and the 3rd row will remain 3rd
4. The max row count is 15 so the string can be of the form `123456789ABCDEF`, or in case the solution with this reduced form is not simple, the string can be of the form `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15`

---

Thanks to many here and out there, I've reached the following solution:

(without the need for functions or loops)

```
-- creating the original table and filling it
DECLARE @t TABLE(Col1 INT, Col2 VARCHAR(22), Col3 CHAR(1));

INSERT @t VALUES
(1,'Jon',   'a'),
(2,'Joan',  'b'),
(3,'John',  'a'),
(4,'Jonnie','b'),
(5,'Jonny', 'a');

-- this is the required order of the results
DECLARE @myOrderString VARCHAR(32) = '213';

-- this is my current solution
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY CHARINDEX(CAST(rr AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), @myOrderString)) As [Row],
    Outcome 
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY Col1) AS rr, 
            Col2 + ' (' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(22),Col1)+ ')' AS Outcome 
        FROM @t 
        WHERE  Col3 = 'a'
    ) as r
ORDER BY 
    [Row]
```

but,it works for up to 9 rows of a result, while I have up to 15 rows represented of the form `123456789ABCDEF`.

I tried to employ Dec to Hex convertion on result's row numbers by using `CONVERT(CHAR(1),CONVERT(VARBINARY(1),@Dec))`, but with no luck.

**Is there a *simple* correction available for this to work?**

---

### A long example (longer than 9 rows)

In order to test an example longer than 9 rows, I use this:

```
-- creating the original table and filling it
DECLARE @t TABLE(Col1 INT, Col2 VARCHAR(22), Col3 CHAR(1));

INSERT @t VALUES
(1,'Jon',   'a'),
(2,'Joan',  'b'),
(3,'John',  'a'),
(4,'Jonnie','b'),
(5,'Jonny', 'a'),
(6,'Don',   'a'),
(7,'Doan',  'b'),
(8,'Dohn',  'a'),
(9,'Donnie','b'),
(10,'Donny', 'a'),
(11,'Gon',   'a'),
(12,'Goan',  'a'),
(13,'Gohn',  'a'),
(14,'Gonnie','a'),
(15,'Gonny', 'a');

-- this is the required order of the results
DECLARE @myOrderString VARCHAR(32) = '456B213A789';
```

---

### A full solution:

I'll provide here my full solution using a loop at the answers section, without taking credit for it as THE answer.

Comment: What happens if you have more than 9 rows in your table?

Comment: Why does your output include `Jonnie (4)`? Shouldn't that row be `Jonny (5)` instead?

Comment: I would have left it as 3,1,4 and just swapped the col3 values on rows 4 and 5. Now you have a bunch of answers that look at 3,1,4 and it may be confusing for future readers.

Comment: @aaron-bertrand Thanks for the comment, see clarification.

Comment: Your row outcome is still wrong then (about in the middle of the question). I'd still suggest going back to 3,1,4 and just changing Jonnie's col3 to a and Jonny's col3 to b. Then the answer will make sense without having to edit those as well. And you can remove all the justification for edits. I can do this for you if you like (and then remove my comments here). I'm afraid all the edits are just going to add more confusion now and in the future.

Comment: I still think you're not following me. Your @myOrderString is '213' but your row outcome (now edited again) implies it was '315'. This is still confusing.

Comment: @aaron-bertrand - 3,1,4 has no importance. The question is about sorting results by the result row numbers.
I will update each answer writers.
BTW, see clarifications.
Thanks.

Comment: I think the original question was *very* confusing because every single person who answered seemed to think that 3,1,4 correlated to the col1 values. The question is still somewhat confusing in my eyes but I have updated my answer to reflect what I think you've been after all along (just didn't communicate accurately).

Comment: I want to +1 for an interesting problem, but -3 for presenting a confusing problem, suggesting options that weren't real options, and changing the requirements after people worked relatively hard formulating incorrect solutions. (Which led to many people also getting down-voted either because the answer didn't solve your problem or because they didn't understand that the answer solved what you initially asked for but not what you wanted.)

Comment: @aaron-bertrand - I disagree. The question is clear as it was, but the misleading errors (this is the nature of errors). There were only two errors which I fixed ASAP. I've never changed requirements. I made clarifications as asked (like  the 15 rows). I do not know who down-voted (I don't have permission for that). The down-vote made before I fixed the errors, so we will probably never know who and why did that. I'm not after reputation, but for interesting questions and answers. The delimiter IS an option, but only if should/must separate the values.

Comment: Initially your question said something like "if the orderstring needs delimiters, it can" - that is a very different thing than what you're stating now. And if you don't think that your requirements have changed since answers started coming in, then I guess we'll have to agree to disagree about what a requirement change is. When I post an answer that includes a function, and conforms to your willingness to use a comma-separated string, then you say that's not good enough, that's changing requirements. And let me remind you that your question has been edited ELEVEN TIMES.

Comment: @aaron-bertrand - I was sure I made much more edition, because I saved the question even after changing typos, 3 edition was for separating lines and titles, 2 for clarifications, 3 for answer and so on, so I left with only one edition for corrections based on comments - some were yours. I still have the same P.S line regarding the commas, and I have nothing against these, I have nothing against function as well. I just have preferences and more important curiosity and a strong will to know. It's okay to disagree, however, I'm willing provide explanations as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Making your string comma-separated is going to be much better. You can use a split function like this:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitInts
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number),
        Item FROM (SELECT Number, Item = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
        CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)))
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
      FROM sys.all_objects) AS n(Number)
      WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
      AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, 1) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(Item) = 1
  );
GO
```

Now you can do this:

```sql
DECLARE @myOrderString VARCHAR(32) = '2,1,3';

DECLARE @t TABLE(col1 INT, col2 VARCHAR(32), col3 CHAR(1));

INSERT @t VALUES
(1,'Jon',   'a'),
(2,'Joan',  'b'),
(3,'John',  'a'),
(4,'Jonnie','b'),
(5,'Jonny', 'a');

SELECT 
  [Row] = s.Number, 
  Outcome = t.col2 + ' (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), t.col1) + ')' 
FROM 
(
  SELECT col1, col2, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1)
  FROM @t WHERE col3 = 'a'
) AS t 
INNER JOIN 
  dbo.SplitInts(@myOrderString, ',') AS s
  ON s.Item = t.rn 
ORDER BY s.Number;
```

Again, results:

```sql
Row  Outcome
--   ----------
1    John (3)
2    Jon (1)
3    Jonny (5)
```

**EDIT**

Here is a version that doesn't use a function (though I'm not sure why that is so objectionable in this case), doesn't require the list to become comma-separated (a new "hard" requirement, according to the OP's self-answer), and doesn't have to manually populate a table variable in a loop before proceeding (which leads to a less expensive overall plan, even if the final query in the OP's answer does look cheaper when you ignore the loop + inserts). This returns the same results as the OP's self-answer (given the new "A long example" sample data added to the question) but is likewise limited to 15 maximum sort values.

```sql
;WITH n(n,c) AS 
(
  SELECT CASE WHEN n < 10 THEN n ELSE n -7 END, CHAR(n+48)
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT TOP (21) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])
    FROM sys.objects ORDER BY [object_id]
  ) AS x WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND 9 OR n BETWEEN 17 AND 21
),
x(Outcome, n) AS 
(
  SELECT col2 + ' (' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), col1) + ')', 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1)
  FROM (SELECT col1, col2 FROM @t WHERE col3 = 'a') AS y
)
SELECT [Row] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(n.c, @myOrderString), 0), 16)), 
  Outcome FROM x LEFT OUTER JOIN n ON x.n = n.n
ORDER BY [Row], Outcome;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm the writer of the question. I do not take credit for this answer as THE answer.

This solution is based on looping on each of the `@myOrderString` charachters.

This solution is given here as for inspiration, hoping for a solution based on the solution I described in the question.

### Creating the original table and filling it:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Col1 INT, Col2 VARCHAR(32), Col3 CHAR(1));

INSERT @t VALUES
(1,'Jon',   'a'),
(2,'Joan',  'b'),
(3,'John',  'a'),
(4,'Jonnie','b'),
(5,'Jonny', 'a'),
(6,'Don',   'a'),
(7,'Doan',  'b'),
(8,'Dohn',  'a'),
(9,'Donnie','b'),
(10,'Donny', 'a'),
(11,'Gon',   'a'),
(12,'Goan',  'a'),
(13,'Gohn',  'a'),
(14,'Gonnie','a'),
(15,'Gonny', 'a')
```

### This is the required order of the results

```
DECLARE @myOrderString VARCHAR(32) = '456B213A789'
```

### Converting the string into a table with an Order Colomn (OC)

I wish there were a built-in function to convert a [delimited] string into a table that does something like this.

```
DECLARE @ot TABLE (PK INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, OC INT)
DECLARE @i int
SET @i = 0
WHILE @i < LEN(@myOrderString) 
    BEGIN
        SET @i = @i + 1
        IF ASCII(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@myOrderString,@i,1))) < 65
            INSERT @ot VALUES (SUBSTRING(@myOrderString,@i,1))
        ELSE
            INSERT @ot VALUES (ASCII(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@myOrderString,@i,1)))-55)
    END
```

### presenting results in the required order:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PK) AS [Row], 
    r.Outcome 
FROM @ot 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col1) AS [RRow], 
        Col2 +' (' + CONVERT(varchar(11), Col1) + ')' AS Outcome
    FROM @t 
    WHERE Col3 = 'a') AS r
ON OC=RRow
```

### Appendix

For an interesting result (selecting rows of the result - not required) try to set `@myOrderString = '333222111'`

Comment: Did you try the solution I posted?

Comment: @aaron-bertrand - Yes I did. I find this (my) solution more elegant because it is strait forward, does not require a function and does not require a delimiter. I would like to get rid of the loop, like I showed in the partial solution (up to 9 rows) published within the question. If no solution of this preferred type will be posted or I will not find a solution, your solution will probably be the chosen one. What is you opinion on both my solutions?

Comment: What is wrong with having a function - especially since you can reuse it to solve other problems too? Why is creating a table variable and inserting a bunch of rows in a loop better? And if it is a requirement to not have a delimiter, why would your question offer that as an option? If your preference is to allow your sort string to be `419A57B` then state that. Though I don't know why you want to limit yourself to that - someday you may need to sort on more than 15 rows. I don't find anything elegant at all about using hex to represent numerical order, and not sure why commas are so bad.

Answer (score 1):

If you make you're string commasepearated, you an insert it into a temp table and join on that table, the temp table can then contain a sequence number that is incremented each time you insert one of youre integers from the commaseperated string, and that is what you order by

And here is a very fast example (there is propably room for optimization)

```
DECLARE @string varchar(max),
    @delimiter char(1),
    @xml xml

SELECT @string = '3,1,4',
    @delimiter= ','

SELECT @xml = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@string,@delimiter,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>')

create table #values
(
    seq integer identity(1, 1),
    value integer
)

insert into #values (value)
SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(20)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/s') T(c)

select
    v.seq,
    m.Col2,
    m.Col1
from dbo.myTable m
inner join #values v on m.Col1 = v.value
order by v.seq

drop table #values
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There were errors which are now correted. I have added a clarification according to comments. If you may, please inspect the question again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per the requirements, Below mentioned is the solution...

```
Select col1, Col2 + ' (' + Convert(Varchar, col1) + ')'
From #T
Where CHARINDEX(CAST(Col1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '3,1,4') <> 0
order by CHARINDEX(CAST(Col1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), '3,1,4')
```

### Edit -2 The non numeric values are being ignored in the UDF.

### EDIT - 1 Supports the values greater then 9

```
declare @myTable table(col1 int, col2 varchar(10), col3 varchar(1))

insert @myTable values
(1,'Jon',   'a'),
(2,'Joan',  'b'),
(322,'John',  'a'),
(4,'Jonnie','b'),
(5,'Jonny', 'a')

Select col1, Col2 + ' (' + Convert(Varchar, col1) + ')'
From @myTable T
INNER JOIN 
(
    Select * From dbo.Split('322,1,4', ',')
)K
ON K.val = T.col1
Order by K.id
```

---

### User Defined Function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (id int IDENTITY(1,1), Val Int)       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(isnumeric(@slice) = 0) 
        Set @slice = '';

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Val) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end
```

Comment: @kanavi - Thanks for you answer. There were errors which are now correted. I have added a clarification according to comments. If you may, please inspect the question again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your output table isn't possible given the data supplied because Jonnie is a 'b' not an 'a'.  Also, in the example below, 'Jonny' is an 'a' but is not returned because 5 is not in the supplied sort string.  Some guidance is needed on how to handle rows like that.

```
declare @sortTable table (sortId int identity, sortOrder varchar(1))
declare @sortString nvarchar(100) = '314'

declare @position int = 1
declare @sortOrder varchar(1) = substring(@sortString,@position,1)
while @sortOrder != ''
begin
    insert @sortTable (sortOrder) values (@sortOrder)
    set @position = @position + 1
    set @sortOrder = SUBSTRING(@sortString,@position,1)
end


declare @myTable table(col1 varchar(1), col2 varchar(10), col3 varchar(1))

insert @myTable values
(1,'Jon',   'a'),
(2,'Joan',  'b'),
(3,'John',  'a'),
(4,'Jonnie','b'),
(5,'Jonny', 'a')

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rsSort.SortID) AS Row, ( Col2 + '(' + Col1 + ')' ) AS Outcome
FROM @myTable rsMain
inner join @sortTable rsSort on rsSort.sortOrder = rsMain.col1
WHERE Col3 = 'a'
```

[Working Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73187)

Comment: Thanks for you correction. Thanks for you answer too. There were other errors which are now correted. I have added a clarification according to comments. If you may, please inspect the question again. Thanks.